# PHP Pre printed Certificates printing with dynamic user values

Tags: php, cakephp, printing, certificate

My client has pre-printed certificates, which we've to use and print again with dynamic user's values on it using PHP / CakePHP.

client says, he will scan them and then he can choose the location where `[name]` will be printed, where `[dates]` and `[score]` will be printed, so any ideas how we can achieve such things?

One thing, i had seen from friend's ref, is they are creating PDF file, using PDF Pro version and there, they are replacing text box [txtbox] with dynamic values using .Net, so any idea/guide to achieve the same with php / cakephp.

thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use tcpdf to generate a pdf from php using html and a bit of css, or you can use a jpg/png image and place the text over it , there are tons of tutorials on both out there .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi
I had done the same thing previously.

My first question is - is the type of certificate your client needs is consitent (single)? Since my method requires a bit of adjusting the layout with CSS

So what you can do is take the layout of the certificate (jpg after scanning).
Now take the values to be printed on the certificate in a form or through the database (your own logic), open a new popup (using JS) which is essentially an HTML page with the certificate image as Background and place the textboxes at the appropriate location on that page and tell the JS on that page to print the page.

You'll also need to adjust the browser properties (popups and header/footerless printing).

Comment: thanks for your answer.. yes the certificate format/layout will be same for a year, new year, might change, but that's not an issue for us now.. please share your link, where you have implement such a code, for review so i can have better idea on it